# Trying to understand the behaviour of execlp in a for loop

Tags: c, linux, exec

```
main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int i;
    for(i=1;i<argc;i++)
    {
        execlp(argv[i],"",NULL);
    }
}
```

I want to execute multiple commands concurrently from the command line input. 
so, in the command line i have given `./a.out date & cal & pwd & ls`

In the output, i could execute all the commands concurrently.

But when i call execlp for the first time, it should take the first argument i.e., argv[1], and should replace the whole process by process-date and should terminate the whole process after its execution. But if it terminates then how come it is able to continue the for loop again ??

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop doesn't continue. Only the first command will be run, and replace the process when `execlp` is run (assuming success).

But if you print the value of `argc`, you'll see that it's equal to 2, i.e. the for loop would only run for one iteration even if there wasn't an `execlp` call. This is because in the shell, when you run `a & b & c &`, it will run each of the commands `a`, `b`, `c` in the background separately. In this case, it calls your process with the commandline `./a.out date`. The other commands are run by the shell directly and not by your process.

Comment: oh OK thanks. so if i use system(argv[i]) will it reflect the same behavior?

Comment: @SREEBALATHATAVARTHI `system` doesn't replace the current process, and it waits for the command to complete, so it's quite different. If you're only running one command like here and not doing anything afterwards then the results will appear similar.

Comment: oh.. That means ./a.out date will be executed by the loop for the first time and cal & pwd & ls will be executed by the loop for the second time. Am I right?

Comment: @SREEBALATHATAVARTHI No. I'm not sure what you mean by "second time", but `cal & pwd & ls` are not passed to your program as parameters at all. Print the values inside `argv` to see.

Answer (score 1):

It's not your program that's running `cal`, `pwd` and `ls`, it's the shell that you're using. It calls your program with the only argument `date`, and runs it in the background. Then starts `cal`, `pwd` and `ls` also in the background.

Remove the `&` or put them in quotes if you want your program to receive them as parameters. Then you'll see that indeed your program doesn't run the loop (unless `execl` fails).

Answer (score 1):

Read documentation of [execlp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execlp.3.html) (and more generally of every function you are using). Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/).

If you want to pass `date`, `cal`, `pwd`, `ls` to your program `a.out` you need to run the command `a.out date cal pwd ls` (without any `&` which is interpreted by your [shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_%28computing%29)). The shell is [globbing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_%28programming%29) arguments for your program. See [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html).

BTW, don't name your program `a.out`. Use something like

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g yourprog.c -o yourprog
```

to compile your code then run `./yourprog` (perhaps inside the `gdb` debugger).

The `execlp` function calls the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall which *does not return on success*. So both `execlp` and `execve` are returning only on failure.

So the first time you are executing your loop, the program stops because `date` was successfully executed (and that means `date` has *replaced* `./yourprog` in its [process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29)).

Maybe you want to execute a sequence of programs till one is found (e.g. `./yourprog silly date` with `silly` not existing in your system). Then you should code something like

```
for(i=1;i<argc;i++) {
    execlp(argv[i],"",NULL);
    // this is reached only if the above `execlp` failed, so
    perror(argv[i]);
}
```

More likely, you want to execute every program in turn (e.g. `./yourprog date id ls`). Then you'll need to call [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) *inside* your loop. You'll keep the result of `fork` and you should test against failure of `fork`. In the child process, you'll call [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) or  [execlp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execlp.3.html). In the parent process, you need to call [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) to avoid [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

Another possibility is if you want to run all the programs at once. You'll need two loops, one doing the `fork`-s (and keeping the child pids in some array), and another doing the [wait(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html).

If you want to e.g. read the output of the programs you are running in a child process (or write their standard input) you'll need to learn about [pipe(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html)-s and call [pipe(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html) *before* `fork`. If you want to run them in parallel and read from several pipes you'll need to use a multiplexing syscall like [poll(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)